# After running VM Workstation - Delete Key opens "Task Manager"

Tags: vmware-workstation

After using VM Workstation (open use then exit program) any time I hit the Delete key - the task manager pops up. I can restart my machine to eliminate this issue. Any ideas on how to remap the key to it's original delete function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried hitting ctrl + alt before exiting the vmware guest?

Answer (score 0):

I closed an operation called "sidebar.exe" (running my wife's Coke points or some gadget) and that immediately got rid of the problem (TAB was also going to the tab processes window).